# Installing openssh-server on a virtual machine

Tags: openssh

I am unable to install openssh-server on an Ubuntu 13.10 virtual machine. Here is the command I used and it's output:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
[sudo] password for mohamed:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package openssh-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openssh-server' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In software sources settings enable (if not enabled) main, multiverse and universe sources, then run `sudo apt-get update`, and try it again.

Comment: Thank you, before posting my question I have enabled the multiverse sources, but I didn't know I have to apt-get update afterwards.